# Find derivative of function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help in finding the derivative. I don't even know where to begin with it. I'm learning chain rule in school and do not see how I can apply that here.

$$
f(x)=\left(\dfrac {x+1}{x^2+8}\right)^6
$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $g(x)=(h(x))^n$, then the Chain Rule implies that $$g'(x)=n(h(x))^{n-1}\cdot h'(x).$$

Comment: $$
f(x)=6\left(\dfrac {x+1}{x^2+8}\right)^5 * \frac {(2x)(x+1)}{(x^2+8)^2}
$$
Using quotient rule to get h'(x). Is that right?

Comment: That would be absolutely correct but you need to look at your quotient rule again.

Comment: Is it not (f'(x)g(x) - g'(x)f(x)) / g(x)^2? Derivative of numerator (f'(x)) is 0 no?

Comment: No $y=x+1$ is a line of slope one so its derivative is 1 ;)

Comment: Oh right. Would that make it
$$
\frac {(x^2+8)-(2x^2+2)}{(x^2+8)^2}
$$
I guess I could simplify it even more.

Comment: Yes but it should be $-(2x^2+2x)$. Yes simplify the top if possible. There are a few good reasons for leaving the bottom as it is.

Answer (score 2):

One way to apply the chain rule is to make a substitution.  If you let
$$u=\frac{x+1}{x^2+8}$$
then your function can be written as
$$y=u^6$$
and the chain rule says
$$f'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\,\frac{du}{dx}\ .$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: No, still confused.

Comment: You should be able to calculate $dy/du$ because $y$ in terms of $u$ is very simple.  And you should be able to calculate $du/dx$ by using a rule you learnt before you got as far as the chain rule.

Comment: All the dy/dx, dy/du, etc... is foreign to me. I've memorized rules, none of which had dy/dx, etc... So I have no idea what you mean when you say "calculate dy/du because y in terms of u..."

Comment: If $y=f(x)$ then $dy/dx$ is another way of writing $f'(x)$.  It is a **very** common notation and I am surprised your teacher has not shown it to you.  But since that's the case I guess you had better not try to do the problem this way.

Comment: I see, I'll remember this and ask my teacher about it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use logarithmic differentiation here: https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/logarithmic-differentiation-calculator/?f=%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B8%29%29%5E6